# Rows don't show up when searching/filtering specific column

Tags: 2013, search, filter

I'm new to Sharepoint 2013 and have a little problem:

I have a big list with more than 5000 elements, now i want to filter the list via a view filter[image]

I know that this filter should return less than 5000 elements, but it just keeps saying that the view contains more than 5000 elements.

Another problem, is that when I search in the search box of the list, lets say for 222, it returns nothing even if the VLAN ID with the number 222 exists in my list.
[image]

The other columns in the list a fully functional (I can search for them and use them for filtering).

Answer (score 0):

Guten Abend!

There is a setting called 'List View Threshold' under Central Administration -> Manage Web Applications -> Select Your Web Application -> General Settings Dropdown -> Resource Throttling. For filter view you have to ensure filter expression does not exceed the threshold value. 
Note: Changing the threshold value will have a performance impact. 
Regarding the other problem, You can try to make that column searchable: [Making columns searchable for the list](https://www.eliostruyf.com/making-columns-searchable-for-the-list-or-library-searchbox/)

Since you are saying that you have more than 5000 items you should be aware of certain restrictions, I recommend you to go through this [Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784)